# Filter JS Object for Select2 data array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to dynamically populate my [Select2](https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays) dropdown with filtered values from a previous input.

```
var object =    [
        { 
            London: [
                        "112233" : "Company 1",
                        "112244" : "Company 2",
                    ],
            Manchester: [
                        "112255" : "Company 3",
                        "112266" : "Company 4",
                    ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to return an array like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 112233,
        text: 'Company 1'
    },
    {
        id: 11223344,
        text: 'Company 2'
    }
];
```

Just to make this easier, let's say the `city` variable contains my filter criteria. I have the following JS object. My function doesn't work as desired.

```
function getRelatedVenues(city) {
    var venues = [];
    for (var key in object.city)
    {
        venues.push({id:object.city[key],text:object.city[key]});
    }
    return venues;
}

var venueData = getRelatedVenues('London');
```

This returns an empty array.

Comment: Are you sure `object.city` is not empty? What does `console.log(object.city)` give you?

Comment: If I do `console.log(object.London)` it turns a list of all the companies under that array.

Comment: since `city` is not constant, you need to do `object[city]`, not `object.city` which will always look for the literal key `"city"`

Comment: also, it looks like the `id` of the object your pushing should be just `key` (not `object[city][key]`, which gives the "text")`. That's if I've understood your intentions correctly.

Comment: Hey Robin, both your comments above are correct. Can you turn this into an answer please? This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: thanks @Imran - I will do so now. (Should really have done so from the start, but was just pointing things out as I saw them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the function is returning an empty array is that `object.city` is reading the value at the key corresponding to the literal key `"city"`, which of course doesn't exist. Since `city` is a variable, you need to use the square bracket notation to look up the key with that value: `object[city]`.

You also have an error in the `id` of the object that is being pushed onto the array. In all, the function should be amended as follows:

```
function getRelatedVenues(city) {
    var venues = [];
    for (var key in object[city])
    {
        venues.push({id:key,text:object[city][key]});
    }
    return venues;
}
```